# Modify a ListView after setting adapter

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I set an Adapter to a ListView:

```
myListView.setAdapter(new listAdapter(this));
```

in this adapter, I do some operations and I set an Image to the imageView in each lines of the ListView:

```
holder.image.setImageDrawable(anImage)
```

I also have 2 RadioButtons in the project, and what I want to do is changing the image of ONE listView when I check a RadioButton.

My problem: I don't know how "recover" an Image of a line. Does anyone know how I can do it?

Need some help, please.

Comment: What kind of list adapter you are using?

Comment: You mean, when you set image for one item, others are affected too?

Answer (score 1):

Call `ListView.invalidateViews()`. That'll trigger a redraw and set the correct image in `getView()` or `bindView()`.